# How to maintain checkbox value through pagination?

Tags: html, user-interface, checkbox

I have a list of products which are shown with pagination and I can filter the display of the products using check boxes. The problem is it can only displays the value from check box at first page, and if i go to the next page, i will lose the check box checked's value. Please help me how to solve this. I don't know where should I put input hidden and how to write Java Script. Here's my code:

```
<input id="checkbox_brand" type="checkbox"  name="checkbox_brand[<? echo    $data_brand[brand_name]; ?>]" value="<? echo $data_brand[brand_name]; ?>"/>

if (isset($_POST["checkbox_brand"])){
foreach($_POST["checkbox_brand"] as $status_a) {
$status_sql[] = '\''.$status_a.'\'';
}
$status = implode(',',$status_sql);
session_start();
$_SESSION["selected"]=$status;
}

if (session_is_registered("selected")){
-->my query
}
```

Comment: IMO check boxes are not the right choice if there are many records. If the user needs to uncheck a previous selection he will have to go back every page and search. Use check boxes only if the user is able to SEE easily what he has selected. In case of selecting records in large dataset I suggest using something like two list boxes where user selections are placed in one list and the other has the available choices (may be paged as you want). This is much user friendly and will solve your problem as well.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But my user wants the web can show something like this https://www.hartonoelektronika.com/en/television/television-en/led-tv/

Comment: i have done something like this but still cannot work: 

    echo "&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href='$filename?pro=$pro&id=$id&product=$product&page=$next' onclick='document.getElementById('checkbox_brand').submit()'>Next ></a>";

Answer (score 0):

Each time you press a check box you'll have to use dictionary array in JavaScript

For example:
if I use the example page you gave, then when pressing a check box inside "Categories" 
you'll have to put a value inside correct variable.

```
// Initialize Objects
var userChoice = {};
userChoice.Catagories = {};
userChoice.Brands = {};
userChoice.ScreenSize = {};
.
.
.

// Pressing check box will trigger the bellow
userChoice.Categories["LG"] = 0;
userChoice.Categories["Sharp"] = 1;
userChoice.Categories["Sony"] = 1;
userChoice.Brands["LcdTV"] = 1;
userChoice.Brands["LedTV"] = 0;
```

Each checkbox press will also trigger the following JavaScript

```
document.getElementById("userChoiceHiddenField").value = JSON.sringify("userChoice");
```

When submitting the page or going to the next page the hidden value will contain the JSON string, so you can parse it as JSON again.

Server Side: (.NET)

```
string userChoiceHiddenField = request["userChoiceHiddenField"].ToString();
```

and then take the value you got and place it back in the hidden field and the JavaScript value as follows:

```
userChoice = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("userChoiceHiddenField").value);
```

Hope that answers your question.